# How to construct POST urls by reading a file

Tags: api, unix, curl

I have post request that takes a parameter in the following format.

http://someurl/somepath/[objectID]

Also, I have got a list of objectIDs. I would like to know if its possible to run a curl command to execute the POST request by reading the objectIDs stored in a data file as a loop.

Comment: While SO isn't a script writing service and your question doesn't really have enough in it to be a good question here, I'll suggest you might want to look at shell scripts and [`while` loops](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), assuming your objectIDs are "well formed"

Comment: OK, to be clearer, is it possible to pass a list of values in a file to a curl command as a query param within a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem using a bash script that reads a file line by line in a loop and passing $line as the query param to the curl command inside the loop as demonstrated below.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "$line"
  curl -X GET \
  http://someurl/somepath/$line -H 'authorization: Bearer [sometoken]'
printf "\n"
done < "$1"
```